# What exactly the advantage in using gradle in Android development?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been switching from Eclipse to Android Studio for Android development, and now integrating the Facebook SDK (which is a library project), it is quite mind blowing for me that previously I can import the library with a few clicks with less than one minute [1], but now I need to read a whole essay and spent an hour to figure out the same thing.

Can anyone tell me what exactly the advantage in using gradle then?

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/

Comment: Have you at least watched: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325236644

Comment: This looks like issue of facebook SDK creators, that have not worked out quick import